# How to have 3 conditions using both if and while Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Javascript beginner here. I'm trying to compute a simple math function using a window prompt(What is 3+3=?). If the user gets the answer right I want it to report back (Correct!), but if they're one away from the correct answer (5 or 7) I want it to report back another window prompt saying (Very close please try again. What is 3+3?) But also, if they get the answer completely wrong(lets say they put in 2) I want it to report back (Incorrect please try again. What is 3+3=?) This third condition is what is giving me problems because I need 2 separate loops in the script and I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

This is my code so far, where I've got stuck is the third while loop

```
var answer = window.prompt("What is 3+3", "");
    answer=parseFloat(answer);

if(answer==6){
      document.write("Correct!");
}else while( answer==5 || answer==7){
      answer=window.prompt("Very Close Please Try again. What is 3+3", "");
}else while(answer!==6 && answer!==5 && answer!=7){
    answer=window.prompt("Incorrect. Please try again. What is 3+3", "");
}
```

also bonus points to anyone that can explain how I would use a random number and have answer to this number instead of the hard coded 3+3 and its answer.

Comment: Why not "while number != 6"? Or number-6==abs(1)?

Comment: Add `while` at the begining use if instead of while and in `answer==6` use break.

Comment: Are you referring to the 3rd condition? I had while (answer!=6) in before and I couldn't get that to work either. It just loops continuously with Incorrect no matter what number I put in there.

Comment: Your program is syntactically incorrect. There's no such language construct as `while { } else`. You got away with it with first while, as it assumed that this while is within else block from `if(answer==6){`, but now you seem to do something like if with double else, which makes no sense and is in fact not parsing correctly. What you seem to e attempting, is to have single while loop on top level, and within that, do series of `if (answer==6) { /* correct case */ } else if(answer==5 || answer==7) {/* very close case */} else {/* incorrect case */}`. You'd also want to have prompt within loop.

Comment: @jcubic 
So turn them each into separate while loops and add break to the first one?

Comment: No only one while loop that wrap the whole thing as in @gurvinder372 answer.

Comment: @jcubic Thank you for your help also. Still a beginner but at this point I've got to say...Javascript makes so much more sense than PHP haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it will be dynamic. .

```
<body></body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var firstval = 5;
var secondval = 3;

var sum = firstval + secondval;

var answer = parseInt( window.prompt("What is "+firstval+" + "+secondval, ""));

while( answer !== sum )
{
   if ( answer === sum - 1 || answer === sum + 1 )
   {
      answer = parseInt( window.prompt( "Very Close Please Try again. What is "+firstval+" + "+secondval+"", "") );
   }
   else if( answer !== sum )
   {
     answer = parseInt( window.prompt("Incorrect. Please try again. What is "+firstval+" + "+secondval+"", "") );
   }
} 
document.body.innerHTML = "Correct!";
</script>
```

Comment: for firstval and secondval could I use
firstval = math.random();
secondval = math.random();

to create random numbers? that way I wont have to hard code set problems and will have a random sum?

Comment: yeahh , Obvously you can..  use Math.random();   but it will give you a floating number.,  you can convert it to Int and use my code .

Comment: Oh bear with me if I ask pretty obvious questions lol. I'm still learning all of this as I go. But..to convert the floating number to an integer it would be, for instance, (var firstval=math.random()*100;) right?

Comment: var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
try this to get a random int number,.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var answer = parseInt( window.prompt("What is 3+3", "") );

while( answer !== 6 )
{
   if ( answer === 5 || answer === 7 )
   {
      answer = parseInt( window.prompt( "Very Close Please Try again. What is 3+3", "") );
   }
   else if( answer !== 6 )
   {
     answer = parseInt( window.prompt("Incorrect. Please try again. What is 3+3", "") );
   }
} 
document.body.innerHTML = "Correct!";
```

Comment: Thank you sir, now I understand...While loops must be top level and the if statements must set inside the while loop. Also I want to thank you for the parseInt(window.prompt(code here)); I did not know that was possible to do in one line. 

p.s And also document.body.innerHTML works a lot better than document.write.